# A Linear map $‎u : X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎‎$ ‎ ‎is ‎not ‎bounded ‎below ‎‎iff ‎there ‎is ...

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras, compact-operators

Do you help me to:

c‎hecking ‎that a‎‎ ‎linear ‎map ‎‎$‎u : X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎‎$ ‎between ‎Banach ‎spaces ‎is ‎not ‎bounded ‎below ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎there ‎is a‎ ‎sequence ‎of ‎unit ‎vector ‎‎$‎(‎x‎‎_{‎n‎}‎)$ ‎in ‎‎$‎X$ ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎‎\lim‎_{‎n‎\rightarrow ‎\infty‎} ‎‎u(‎x‎_{‎n‎}‎)=0‎$‎‎

Comment: A ‎linear ‎map ‎‎$‎u : X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎‎$ ‎between ‎Banach ‎spaces ‎is ‎bounded ‎below ‎if ‎there ‎is positive number $\delta‎$ such that $‎\Vert ‎u(x) ‎\Vert‎\geq‎‎ ‎\delta ‎\Vert x \Vert‎$ ($‎\forall ‎‎x‎ \in ‎X‎$‎‎)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ is not bounded below then for each $n$ there exists $z_n$ such that $\| u(z_n)\|<\frac{1}{n}\|z_n\|$. In particular $\|z_n\|\neq 0$. Now define $x_n=\frac{z_n}{\|z_n\|}$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of unit vectors such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u(x_n)=0$. The other implication is easy.